# how to protect react.js spa with .net core api

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I am trying to protect a react.js spa app with adal login and authenticate with .net core wepApi.

I am able to get JWT from azure invoked by react SPA (using react-adal module) and retrieve basic user information.

**Now the joy begins**
As most MSFT examples are based on their mvc approach, they have a password to sign token in the webconfig file, which is not accessible for frontend application.

How then I could sign the JWT token using a password without pushing it to the SPA app as that could be read in a web console?

One of my ideas is to initiate login in the SPA, then use a webapi endpoint as a redirect link (and provide a connection id in state field) and then by ajax I could do redirect on the SPA, but still there is no signature on the JWT.

Answer (score 0):

my partial solution at the moment is:

1. have `react-adal` used to validate if user is logged-in
2. when there is no token, then `react-adal` authenticates, but redirection is on a special page when I am grabbing the token and store it in database. The trick here is: there is a need to change `hash` to `query-string` to grab the token serverside (as all after # is not forwarded to web-server), so a simple javascrip that replaces `#` with `?` and redirects to another endpoint.
3. then redirect to the main application

As the URL is only used for redirects (after adal login ) - that is a typical `man-in-the-middle` scenario, but gives an ability to generate own token.